# Why does Visual Studio breaks to the next line before I finish typing

Tags: laravel, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio for my Laravel project. There are times when I am typing the Route code in routes\web.php that the cursor breaks to the next line before I finish typing. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Isn't it the word-wrap parameter?

Comment: @Mondini On the settings, Controls how lines should wrap is off. Controls how lines should wrap is 80. Any setting I'm missing out?

Answer (score 1):

I've turned off the auto save setting. This seemed to solve the problem